# Firestore transaction: set id of the first document to the second document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I'm trying to add two documents to two different collections.

say coll1 & coll2.

I add a document to coll1 => I get the document id which I would like to set it to the coll2 document as id, I can simply write two add's but I'm trying to get these done in a transaction, so that if one fails both fail.

I could not get that done using [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Below is the code I've, which needs to be turned to transations/batched:

```
await db.runTransaction(
      async function (transaction) {
        const coll1 = {
          text: 'This is collection 1 text',
        }

        const coll1Doc = await db
          .collection('coll1')
          .add(coll1)
        // I tried transaction.set(db.collection('coll1').doc(), coll1) but this doesn't return the doc or the docId which we need in the next step.
        // Similay batch.set is also not returning the newly added/edited doc or its Id.

        if (coll1Doc && coll1Doc.id) {
          const coll1Id = coll1Doc.id
          const coll2 = {
            text: 'This is collection 2 text',
          }
          await db
            .collection('coll2')
            .doc(coll1Id)
            .set(coll2)
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: "I could not get that done using this link" -> Edit your question to show what you tried please.

Comment: added my code & comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore document IDs are generated inside your application code, and are statistically guaranteed to be unique. So your `add()` call, essentially takes these two steps:

1. Generate a new unique ID
2. Create a `DocumentReference` for that ID
3. Set the data in that `DocumentReference`

With that knowledge, you can build a `DocumentReference` yourself based on an ID that you get without using the transaction object.

```
const coll1Doc = db
  .collection('coll1')
  .doc();
const id1 = coll1Doc.id;
await coll1Doc.set(coll1);
```

Now you can use `id1` in the second write operation.

Comment: What is doc.id??
Also I was able to do this... but I'm looking to do this in transactions or batches... so that it will be reverted if anything goes wrong!

Comment: `doc.id` was a typo, I updated it now. You can use this `id1` in transaction operations too.